# Adding two df columns with different sizes with condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have two df with different size. I have to add loan_amnt column in df1  and  df2 with matching account_num, if in df2 no matching account_num, then pass it and paste value from df1. Finally from result subtract df3.

first df1:

```
account_num loan_amnt   
124    1359467
125    2537290
126    9152838
127    7738935
129    4446699
130    1176879
131    2629022
132    7497333
143    4992738
144    3483429
148    1027315
149    3529133
150    3481139
```

second df2:

```
account_num loan_amnt
124    6334892
125    4384097
126    1110000
127    4110000
129    3344000
131    1171246
132    4326000
143    1100310
149    2843147
```

third df3

```
account_num loan_amnt
124    1360100
125    2119064
126    8600635
127    7749935
129    4767909
130    9088889
131    2631015
132    1003917
143    5413355
144    3446656
148    1027315
149    3749521
150    3266721
```

Formula is: result_df = (df + df2) - df3

I've tried various methods, but didn't get expected result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use if `account_num` are index for each DataFrame use [`DataFrame.add`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add.html) and [`DataFrame.sub`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sub.html) with `fill_value=0` parameters:

```
result_df = df.add(df2, fill_value=0).sub(df3, fill_value=0)
```

If column `account_num` create index first:

```
result_df = (df.set_index('account_num')
               .add(df2.set_index('account_num'), fill_value=0)
               .sub(df3.set_index('account_num'), fill_value=0)
               .reset_index())
```

Answer (score 1):

I think jezreal's answer looks better, but this is may be easier to understand:

```
import pandas as pd


df1 = pd.DataFrame({'acc': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'loan': [10, 12, 14, 16]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'acc': [1, 3, 4], 'loan': [10, 14, 16]})
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'acc': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'loan': [5, 4, 3, 2]})

df1.set_index('acc', inplace=True)
df2.set_index('acc', inplace=True)
df3.set_index('acc', inplace=True)

result_df = df1.copy()
result_df.loc[df2.index] += df2
result_df -= df3
```